# Chrome is putting suggested URL in parentheses, making it uneditable - how to stop this?

Tags: google-chrome

In a recent update, when I type a partial URL into the address bar, Chrome has started putting the suggested URL in parentheses after what I type, which means I'm not able to edit that URL before I press ENTER.

See example image below. Previously, when I typed the letters **capt**, and the first URL suggested is the one I'm trying to edit, I could press the down arrow once and it would put that URL into the address bar, and I was then free to edit that URL before pressing ENTER to visit it.

After a recent update, when I type the letters **capt**, the URL I'm trying to edit appears in the address bar in parentheses after what I type (you can see it in blue in the image), but I can't edit it.  When I press the down arrow to try to select the URL from the list like I did before, the focus moves to the second thing in the dropdown. When I press the up arrow, it moves the selection back to the address bar with the URL still in brackets.

This is annoying because I have lots of similar URLs that I visit, and I was always able to type part of a URL, have Chrome fill in the full URL, and then I could edit the URL directly before pressing ENTER.  Since the update, I can no longer do that - I have to visit the URL, and only then can I edit it.

Is there a way to stop Chrome putting the URL in parentheses in the address bar after what I type, and revert it back to its previous behaviour where it was editable?  My Chrome version is Version 106.0.5249.181.

Thanks!

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried settings > "reset and clean up"?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I don't remember changing any settings recently, so I'm hesitant to do that - this will be a last resort.

Comment: Press "RIGHT ARROW" !

Comment: @Prem doesn't work unfortunately, the cursor just will not move within the brackets no matter if I push right arrow, click on it, or anything else I tried.

Comment: Now I updated to latest & I am not seeing this Issue. Try "END" & "HOME". Try updating to latest.

Comment: I'm on Version 107.0.5304.107 (Official Build) (64 bit) and I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: correct term is "parentheses" (), not "brackets" []

Comment: **Reproducible** on latest (107.0.5304.110). Workaround: Press `Tab` x 2, then `Shift + Tab`

Comment: Yeah, although this seems to be an intentional feature, this is definitely a UX bug, filed a Chromium bug here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1394443

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> **Update [2022-12-01]**
>
> - Chromium bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1394443 (with thanks @Karl Horky)
> - This is *absolutely* unintuitive as a workaround - if there's ever a fix or better workaround, someone please change the accepted "answer" over accordingly

---

**Workaround to edit the url:**

1. Type partial url until suggestion appears in parentheses
2. Press `Tab`
3. Press `Tab` *again*
4. Press `Shift + Tab`

When focus returns to the url/search bar the suggested link changes from the parenthesised "suggestion" to an ordinary text url

For a shorter variation, this appears to work as well:

1. Type partial url until suggestion appears in parentheses
2. Press `Shift + Tab`
3. Press `Tab`

Comment: That's fantastic. Not at all intuitive but it works, and I'm glad I'm not the only one with the problem!!

Comment: Seems like this workaround may be a bug that the Chrome team will later "fix". Would be much better for Chrome to provide an option to disable this functionality (or even better - Chrome team could revert this "feature" ). Horrible UX.

Comment: Thanks! After playing with your workarounds, I found a variant I like better: `Tab` then `Up` (tested on v111.x). For some reason, I'm too clumsy for `Shift+Tab` 

Comment: Tab,Tab,Shift+Tab doesn't work if the URL has an associated "search in [website]"; in such cases you'd need to press Tab a 3rd time before Shift+Tab. Hence the Shift+Tab,Tab combo is more consistent, I think.

Answer (score 5):

This was causing me problems for other reasons, but I disabled these chrome://flags and one of them seems to have removed the change:

Omnibox Rich Autocompletion Promising Combinations

Omnibox shortcut expanding

History Journeys Omnibox Action

Comment: Disabling `Omnibox Rich Autocompletion Promising Combinations` does make this behaviour go away, but it also loses the "auto-completion" in the URL too so you still have to use tab or the keyboard arrows to get to the suggestion you want to copy/paste the URL which is still a net negative (though better than the current default)

Comment: At first glance disabling the first one has fixed my problem, thanks!  I'll work with that setting disabled for a while and see if it has any unwanted side effects for me!

Comment: As of today, the first option is of course no longer there.